# Attribute selection to add text?

Tags: html, css

I'm seeking for a latex-like theorem environment for my blog, and find the following css:
`.thm[text]:before { content: "Theorem " counter(thm) "(" attr(text) "). "; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; }`
My attempt is to render content like following picture:
[image]
The point is to show text "prime number" after Theorem 1.

I typed the following html code:
`<div class="thm">[prime number] All odd numbers are prime.</div>`
But it didn't work out as my expect. I have tried other html, such as putting '[prime number]' in the angle brackets, and it still failed. Can anyone post the correct code so that it shows like the picture?

Comment: There is more context that you need to show us. The code you have shown seems to be mixing up HTML, CSS and text. I should start by reading up about the before pseudo element in CSS and then the counter property..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```html
<div class="thm" text="prime number" counter="1">
   All odd numbers are prime.
</div>
```

```css
.thm:before { 
  content: "Theorem " attr(counter) "(" attr(text) "). "; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```